# Move the row if the next cell of the row is empty

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I possibly move one (1) row if the next row has an empty value?

For example like this.

[image: OP example]

Comment: How did the data generate in Table 2?

Comment: What do you mean by MOVE,, did you mean to say Move the Row Up or Down to the Empty Row?

Comment: First, insert an empty new row before LV02. Then you can move the row.

Comment: @RajeshS I want to move it down sir

Comment: @AlexAbulencia,, your Screen Shot shows Row that has LV01 had all cell filled,, so what you are looking for to Move only value L1K aside to LV02 ,,, or the entire row since this move will overwrite old data!!